# Need command or script to rename a list of files in linux using a pattern match

Tags: bioinformatics, batch-rename

I have downloaded some 90 fasta files from NCBI for bacterial genomes. The downloaded files have default names given by NCBI. I need to change it to my desired file names. Thus I have created two .txt files:

1. file1.txt - having the default files names provided by NCBI. listed out the names provided by NCBI in file1.txt

   [image]
2. file2.txt - having the names to replace the default. listed out the names to replace the NCBI names

   [image]

Both the files are made in an order so that 1st entry of file1.txt is corresponding to 1st entry of file2.txt.

Now all the downloaded files are in a folder. the folder having the files

[image]

and I need a script which reads file1.txt, matches with the file name in the folder and replace it with the names in file2.txt.

I am not a bioinformatician, new to this genre. I look forward to your help. Can this process be made simpler?

Comment: Welcome. Please share examples of your data as plain text in your question rather than images. Thank you.

Comment: File1.txt have: GCF_000408885.1_ASM40888v1_protein.faa, GCF_000876525.1_ASM87652v1_protein.faa, GCF_001042485.2_ASM104248v2_protein.faa, ......................                                        File2.txt have: Bacillus_paralicheniformis_ATCC_9945a, Bacillus_paralicheniformis_BL-09,
Bacillus_paralicheniformis_KJ-16,...............................

Comment: @sowptika Edit the question please adding the file names, rather than adding a comment. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

This can done with a very small [awk](https://people.bath.ac.uk/rjg20/training/bash-scripting/09-awk/) one-liner. For convenience, lets first combine your file1 and file2 to make processing easier. This can be done with `paste file1.txt file2.txt >> names.txt`.

`names.txt` will be a text file with the old names in the first column and the new names in the second. Awk lets us conveniently run through a file line-by-line (or record-by-record in its terminology) and access each column/field.

Assuming you are in the directory with all these files, as well as `names.txt`, you can simply run `awk '{system("mv " $1 " " $2)}' names.txt` to transform them all. This will run through all the lines in `names.txt`, take the filename given in the first column, and move it to the name given in the second column. The `system` command allows you to access more basic file system operations through the shell, like moving `mv`, copying `cp`, or removing `rm` files.

Answer (score 1):

Use [`paste`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/paste.1.html)
and [`xargs`](https://www.gnu.org/software/findutils/manual/html_node/find_html/xargs-options.html) like so:

```
paste file1.txt file2.txt | xargs --verbose -n2 mv
```

The command is using [`paste`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/paste.1.html) to write lines from 2 files side by side, separated by TABs, to STDOUT. The STDOUT is read by `xargs` using a pipe (`|`). Option `--verbose` prints the command, and option `-n2` specifies the max number of arguments for `xargs` to be 2, so that the resulting commands that are executed are something like `mv old_file new_file`.

Alternatively, use the Perl one-liners below.

Print the commands to rename the files, without executing the commands ("dry run"):

```
paste file1.txt file2.txt | perl -lane '$cmd = "mv $F[0] $F[1]"; print $cmd;'
```

Print the commands to rename the files, then actually execute them:

```
paste file1.txt file2.txt | perl -lane '$cmd = "mv $F[0] $F[1]"; print $cmd; system $cmd;'
```

The command is using [`paste`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/paste.1.html) to write lines from 2 files side by side, separated by TABs, to STDOUT. The STDOUT is read by the Perl one-liner using a pipe (`|`) to pass it to Perl one-liner's STDIN.

The Perl one-liner uses these command line flags:
`-e` : Tells Perl to look for code in-line, instead of in a file.
`-n` : Loop over the input one line at a time, assigning it to `$_` by default.
`-l` : Strip the input line separator (`"\n"` on *NIX by default) before executing the code in-line, and append it when printing.
`-a` : Split `$_` into array `@F` on whitespace or on the regex specified in `-F` option.

`$F[0], $F[1]` : first and second elements of the array `@F` into which the line is split. They are old and new file names, respectively.

`system` executes the command `$cmd`, which actually moves the files.

**SEE ALSO:**
[`perldoc perlrun`: how to execute the Perl interpreter: command line switches](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlrun.html#Command-Switches)